# How to install more features to built-in Vim in macOS?

Tags: vimrc, macos

When I type `:version` inside Vim and I got a list of features as below, and I realized that there are some features/packages not installed by default (`-python3` for example). How do I include/install more feature to built-in (macOS version) Vim? Would my changes be overwritten by updates from Apple?

[image: what appears when I type :version in mac Terminal]

Comment: Hello, normally you need to recompile vim to do so (see `:help :version`). PS: I think it's better for you to use `:help [the thing you're looking for]`, `:helpgrep [the thing you're looking for]` or google it. You will be more independent and it will save you the time asking the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and, once you have it installed, get Vim from Homebrew:

```
$ brew install vim
```

Note that Homebrew will install Vim (and all its packages) under `/usr/local`, which will not interfere or remove any system packages.

You should typically configure your system to ensure `/usr/local/bin` appears in `$PATH` ahead of the system directories such as `/usr/bin`, so that the Homebrew versions are the ones that get used.

The default Vim you get from Homebrew (see [formula for Vim here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/vim#default)) comes with support for latest Python, also Ruby, Lua and Perl (see dependencies of the formula.) As a consequence, Homebrew will also install versions of the interpreters and runtime for those languages (so you'll end up with a second copy of them under `/usr/local` as well.)

You can also often control some options of how Homebrew packages get installed by passing `--with` or `--without` options. For example:

```
$ brew install vim --without-perl --with-override-system-vi
```

You might want to read [Homebrew docs](https://docs.brew.sh/) if you plan to use it and want to understand how it works and all it can do.

Comment: Inside system Vim I typed `:echo $VIM` I got `/usr/share/vim` while in Terminal `which vim` I got `/usr/bin/vim`, so what's the difference between these two Vim? btw I have two built-in Vim?

Comment: Actually I did install Homebrew for other reason, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: The `$VIM` variable is not the path to the `vim` binary, but rather a path to where Vim can find its auxiliary files (such as the Vim runtimes and possibly a system-wide vimrc file.) See `:help $VIM` inside Vim to read more about that variable. Both directory `/usr/share/vim` and file `/usr/bin/vim` belong to the system install of Vim. In Homebrew Vim both would be in `/usr/local`.

Comment: Do we really not have a dupe for this? Shocked

Comment: @Ben I often go hunting for duplicates just to find them in S.O. instead... 